# Cucumber step definitions: Is there a way to automate creating them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

Is there a way to create cucumber step definitions manually? Some sort of Rails generator, perhaps?

Right now what I do is `create features/new_feature.feature`, run `cucumber`, create `step_definitions/new_feature_steps.rb`, then copy the step definitions in terminal to `new_feature_steps.rb`.

Is there a faster way of doing this or do I do this manually?

BTW I would appreciate articles on this topic. I am learning Cucumber for our Ruby on Rails app.

I had seen [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118255/cucumber-automatic-step-file-creation) but it hasn't been updated in four years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a very little effort I guess it can be achieved. e.g. This is my feature file.

```
Feature: dummy

Scenario: First
  Given I set sessions to "10"
  Then it should have "10"
```

then in irb

```
s = `cucumber features/adding.feature -d` #=> "Feature: dummy\n\n  Scenario: First...
f = File.new("features/steps.rb","w") #=> create steps.rb file
f.puts s.scan(/(?<=snippets\:).*/m) #=> scan for step definitions and write to steps.rb
f.close
```

Your steps.rb now has

```
Given(/^I set sessions to "(.*?)"$/) do |arg1|
  pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end

Then(/^it should have "(.*?)"$/) do |arg1|
  pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end
```

You can convert this into a command line utility that accepts parameter for filename etc.

Comment: Oh, it has to be from the CLI then. I thought there was some sort of cucumber task or something for this type of thing. Thanks :)